# how to enable Azure CORS for Bot framework?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using bot framework directline hosted in website -html in azure web app. I have enabled the CORS setting as shown below.

[image]

But my Javascript is still showing the same issue when the url www.*.azurewebsites.net

When i run my application using npx serve command it works fine in local but once i uploaded the js and html files to the azure wep app service this issue happens.

Javascript 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run one of the WebChat samples? Instead of opening the HTML file, navigate to the sample directory through the command line and call `npx serve`.   This should launch start the sample on port 5000. Mockbot - the bot the WebChat samples are connected to - has `localhost` configured as a trusted origin but not your file system. However, if you are trying to connect WebChat to a bot you have deployed on Azure, you will have to change how you're requesting your token. Please let me know if that is what you are trying to do, so I can best answer your question.

Comment: I am trying to host the Webchat samples to a website url . Yes with npx serve it works fine locally.

Comment: The issue is with MockBot which doesn't have your URL configured as a trusted origin, so you won't be able to interact with it on your site. [Here](https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-MockBot/blob/0b67dfe5bf09204909299310cbd9892a344c5c68/src/index.ts#L109) is the code where MockBot configures its trusted origins. I would recommend creating your own bot, generating a [DirectLine token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token), and passing the token for your bot to WebChat.